# Running crontab -e with the console on

Tags: command-line, cron, startup, python3

I'm trying to run a python script that uses Selenium to scrap a website on Startup.

After adding `@reboot /Desktop/script.py` to the crontab however (using
`crontab -e`), it seems the script only works when the console is on, and since it opens the script without the console on, the script crashes.

Any ideas on how to fix that? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit, it opens chrome (as it should), but it doesn't work, Chrome closes automatically-

Comment: That's the way I open it everyday when I restart. The full path won't work. /Desktop/script.py attempts to open Chrome, which means it's accessing the script, but since Selenium expects the console to be open, it closes itself.

Answer (score 1):

You must supply full path to your command when defining a cronjob ... so instead of simply  `/Desktop/script.py`  give it `/whatever/is/full/path/to/somescript`

confirm you full path is correct by listing it from a terminal

`ls -la /whatever/is/full/path/to/somescript`

Comment: It indeed is. And it still does the same error. Opens chrome, but fails to do what it's supposed to...